# Animating list view page changes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, visual-studio-2008, animation

I would like to add a player to advance pages of a list view control on a web page.

ORIG: (I'm sure there may be some java script solutions but I would like to not use java script and instead some sort of animation or even AJAX. In the end I need a stable and fast solution. I am stuck with .Net 3.5 in vb.net VS2008.)

**I'll consider any ASP integratable solution.**

All of my search results have not returned any help in this area.

I am familiar with the DataPager and have implemented the control to navigate the listview with a page size of =1. I would like the player to cycle through the listview pages with a start, pause, reverse.

The pager still needs to be able to navigate records as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 0**

- [Datapager control changing pages automatically every 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011828/datapager-control-changing-pages-automatically-every-5-seconds)

---

For a stable and fast solution (which is not free), I'd recommend telerik. It looks like it would be exactly what you need.

- [ListView - Simple vs Advanced Binding](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/databinding/simplevsadvancedbinding/defaultcs.aspx).
- [ListView - Image Gallery](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/listviewsliderwindowrotator/defaultcs.aspx)

There are other solutions. I recommend looking at the answers to the questions below (ranked by possible usefulness).

- [How do I refresh an ASP.NET ListView using jQuery and AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/322318/how-do-i-refresh-an-asp-net-listview-using-jquery-and-ajax)
- [ASP.Net Listview & AJAX Update Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782873/asp-net-listview-ajax-update-panel)
- [how do i use a photo slide show inside listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782665/how-do-i-use-a-photo-slide-show-inside-listview)

Comment: My apologies for not responding sooner, I was victimized by an ice storm here in the northern US. Unfortunately, none of the references or a telerik control provide the play feature to automate the paging operation. The links you provide reveal the same data paging functionality available on the default DataPager control in ASP.net.

Comment: I apologize that my first answers were not exactly what you needed. I added another SO link which it appears you already located. I added it for future users who may stumble on the question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just wasn't sure that the original bounty clearly stated what was needed. You original post did not seem to address that but the added link is almost exactly what I needed. Thanks for following up on this.